# How to Delete attachment in Asana trough API

Tags: asana-api

I have started implementing Asana APIs in my project where I create tasks in a particular project through API and then I add attachments to particular ask using through API,

However, I struggle in the case where **I need to replace the attachment with a new one**, the [asana documentation for attachment](https://developers.asana.com/docs/#asana-attachments) does not  provide a description for any API that can delete/replace an attachment directly neither the edit task API has this option
[image]

So How do I replace(or at least delete so that I can upload a new one), What is the best alternative way?

Comment: Asana's documentation has been updated and this is no longer useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Asana Community forum by *Frederic_Malenfant* stating that

> It looks like the “new documentation” is missing that information!
>
> But, the old one has, and you should send a “DELETE” to the attachment
>   ID, like: DELETE /api/1.1/attachments/123456789 You don’t need to
>   specify the task, just the document ID.

and I tried the DELETE API and it works

> DELETE https://app.asana.com/api/1.1/attachments/:attachment_id

Somehow, the updated documentation is the missing description for the Delete attachment API despite the existence of the API.

Nevertheless,
The response for this delete API is quite weird, it replies empty object with key "`data`" in response as below

```
{
  "data": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete an attachment, you can use the method DELETE with the same url as "Get an attachment". For modifying it, maybe it is possible to do it with PUT or PATCH, but I didn't test it.